# select complete rows using subset of columns from a subquery (single table)

Tags: sql

I am trying to solve the following problem, illustrated in [this table, sql statement and comments](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d3be7/21)

TABLE COLUMNS: id, version, idx_on; PK is 'id' column

So, I get from the subquery a set of tuples{ id, version}.

I want to set the IDX_ON value for all rows which have ID and VERSION the same as those in the subquery' tuples above. Alternately, selecting all rows (ID, VERSION, IDX_ON) with the same criterion would be a good first step.

I tried without success to use something like:
SELECT * FROM docs where ID, VERSION in (*subquery*)

Thanks for any comment...

Answer (score 2):

You can update all rows for which a later version exists:

```
update  (
        select  *
        from    docs d1
        where   exists
                (
                select  *
                from    docs d2
                where   d1.id = d2.id
                        and d2.version > d1.version
                )
        )
set     idx_on = 0;
```

[Updated SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/?_escaped_fragment_=2/8ec17/4#!4/d3be7/14/0)

Comment: @pinkfloydx33's approach is better.

Answer (score 1):

This seemed to work:

```
update docs d
set d.idx_on = 0 
where exists (select * from docs where id = d.id and version > d.version);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Oracle's SQL syntax, if same as in SQL-Server, try this:

```
UPDATE d
SET    d.idx_on = 0
FROM   docs d
       INNER JOIN
              ( SELECT  id,
                       MAX(version) AS "version"
              FROM     docs
              GROUP BY id
              )
              q
       ON     q.id      = d.id
       AND    q.version = d.version
```